# Docker health check targeting anothern container?

Tags: docker, docker-healthcheck

I have a docker container `service-1` that does not support `curl` or `wget` or `ping`. The container does start up a service which is available on `localhost:8080` when ready.

As I cannot write a curl health check for this container (due missing command), I need a nother solution to know, when this container is ready.

My idea was to use another container in the same network, which implements a healthcheck like so:

`curl --fail service-1:8080 || exit 1`

Sadly this seems not work. Can I execute a health check on container A that relies on another container?

Comment: I'd create a new image that has the utilities needed to do a healthcheck in the container

Comment: Kubernetes is a large and complex environment and not appropriate for all workloads, but if you're using it, it natively supports HTTP-request health checks ("probes").

Comment: the containers are part form a local docker compose. no kubernetes involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found this cheeky hack:

```
 test: |
        exec 3<>/dev/tcp/localhost/8080
        echo -e "GET /ready HTTP/1.1\nhost: localhost:8080\n" >&3
        timeout --preserve-status 1 cat <&3 | grep -m 1 status | grep -m 1 UP
        ERROR=$?
        exec 3<&-
        exec 3>&-
        exit $ERROR
```